# How to make JButton add Doubles each time its clicked

Tags: java, double, tostring

I am trying to use a button in order to add doubles each time and have used got this at the moment.

```
btnAnswer3 = new JButton("C");

btnAnswer3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
btnAnswer3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
btnAnswer3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {double scoreAdder, currentScore, ans;
        scoreAdder = 30000.00;
        currentScore = 0.0;

        ans=scoreAdder+currentScore;        

        currentScoretxt.setText(Double.toString(ans)); //This is textfield in which I wish to display the doubles.


        }
    });
```

It already displays a number but once I want it to keep adding up each time the Jbutton is clicked. Please let me know how to do this  using my code. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare this variables out of the `ActionListener`

```
double scoreAdder, currentScore, ans;
```

if not you are just overwriting the math operation and not acumulating the values...

move those declarations and place it as class variables...